# Get access to android notification service from action script

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I,am new to action script and there fore do not know much about action script. I want to get access to android notification service from action script in adobe flash builder. What i want to do is to notify a user through notification about new updates for the app i m developing.

Now I want to know that can I call Java code from action script (native development) to do this task? or do action script alone have power to achieve this? Kindly give me some references or some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [as3c2dm](http://www.riaspace.com/2011/09/as3c2dm-air-native-extension-to-push-notifications-with-c2dm/) AIR native extension to use push notifications in an android AIR app. This is also mentioned on Adobe's official page: [Use Push Notifications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSd6d4f896b3a8801b7be2f55d138e29d5e40-8000.html) (pay attention to the first note on the page)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a "push notification" native extension currently to do this. But be aware C2DM is long depreciated so you shouldn't use the as3c2dm extension suggested by Adobe's Push notification page.

Push notifications for iOS have been built into the AIR SDK but this is not applicable to Android.

You'll need a native extension that supports GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).

This is one I'm currently involved in developing:

- http://distriqt.com/native-extensions

But there are many others, AS3gamegears has a good list of ANEs.

- http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/air-native-extension/